# Laravel 5.4 [View] How to insert input text eg: name:/matrix number: in front of the calling input from the form

Tags: php, html, laravel

my current codes just view the information taken from the registration form. I want to include their title (Name:, matrix Number:) at the front.

I tried  command but it failed.

My output:

[user will be a little confused if I do not put the title at the front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owqhc.jpg)

eg: 
**Name:** Alexandra Rosie
**Matrix Number:** 123456789

Here is my code:

```
      @foreach ($user as $u)
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <input onchange="MakeButtonAble()" class="off" disabled type="text" id="name" name="name" value="{{ Helpers::neat($u->name) }}">
              <hr id="hr-name">
            </div>
            <button onclick="ChangeState('name')" class="btn btn-outline-light customed-edit-button" type="button" name="button">
              <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <input onchange="MakeButtonAble()" class="off" disabled type="text" id="matrix-number" name="matrix-number" value="{{ $u->matrix_number }}">
              <hr id="hr-matrix-number">
            </div>
            <button onclick="ChangeState('matrix-number')" class="btn btn-outline-light customed-edit-button" type="button" name="button">
              <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <input onchange="MakeButtonAble()" class="off" disabled type="text" id="ic-number" name="ic-number" value="{{ $u->ic_number }}">
              <hr id="hr-ic-number">
            </div>
            <button onclick="ChangeState('ic-number')" class="btn btn-outline-light customed-edit-button" type="button" name="button">
              <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <input onchange="MakeButtonAble()" class="off" disabled type="text" id="faculty" name="faculty" value="{{ Helpers::neat($u->faculty) }}">
              <hr id="hr-faculty">
            </div>
            <button onclick="ChangeState('faculty')" class="btn btn-outline-light customed-edit-button" type="button" name="button">
              <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
```

Comment: Do you need to add a label infront  of each input?

Comment: Just add labels before the input elements: `<label for="id_of_the_input_element">Name</label>`

Comment: It is not the input at the registration form. I used the input from the user's registration form to display at their profile. I tried <label> command but it appears above the data at the profile

Comment: I believe you can find a solution by looking at the example of horizontal forms for Bootstrap 4. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#horizontal-form

Comment: the text is not in the form. it is at the view of the user's profile. the tutorial shows to put the text in the form